# How do I affect/select all descendants with Treetable plugin using jQuery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, treetable, descendant

A piece of my HTML code looks like this:

```
<tr data-tt-id="1">
    <td>Parent</td>
</tr>
<tr data-tt-id="2" data-tt-parent-id="1">
    <td>Child 1</td>
</tr>
<tr data-tt-id="4" data-tt-parent-id="2">
    <td>Child 1's child</td>
</tr>
<tr data-tt-id="3" data-tt-parent-id="1">
    <td>Child 2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-tt-id="5" data-tt-parent-id="3">
    <td>Child 2's child</td>
</tr>
```

I'm selecting the parent which has data-tt-id="1" by using this:

```
$('tr[data-tt-parent-id="1"]');
```

But I want all of the children and children's children too, no matter how deep the tree might be.

As you can see data-tt-id is the child's unique ID and data-tt-parent-id is the ID which the child is appended to.

I was thinking about looping through each one of them, but I have no idea how I would achieve that.
How do I select all descendants for the tr that has data-tt-id set to "1"?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon It's more complicated than that, he needs a recursive solution.

Comment: Ok he want the child of his child aswell?

Comment: I want all of the children and children's children too, no matter how deep the tree might be.

Comment: use can try with class instead of id. then for all child parentclass will be same. using classname you can go to any lebel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getDescendants(el, curset) {
    curset = curset || $(""); // default to empty set
    var id = el.data('tt-id');
    var children = $("tr[data-tt-parent-id="+id+"]");
    if (children.length) {
        curset = curset.add(children);
        children.each(function() {
            curset = curset.add(getDescendants($(this), curset));
        });
    }
    return curset;
}
```

There's probably more idiomatic ways to write this without having to reassign `curset = ...` in several places, but this works.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/9xXbB/4/)

Comment: I misspelled the data attribute, I just corrected it. Does that work?